# Magento: Hide dropdown attribute if no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I use this code to hide attributes when they do not have any data:

```
<?php foreach ($_additional[ 'items'] as $_data): ?>
<?php $_attribute=$ _product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']); if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
<tr>
    <th class="label">
        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
    <td class="data">
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works great, but not for attributes type dropdown.
How can I also hide dropdown attributes, that do not have any value?

Answer (score 1):

If an attribute with the type dropdown isn't set, it usually displays as `N/A` on the front-end of your website, so you can simply add `&& $_data['value'] != 'N/A'` to the `if-statement`

So the code would look something like this

```
<?php foreach ($_additional[ 'items'] as $_data): ?>
     <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']); if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '' && $_data['value'] != 'N/A')) { ?>
         <tr>
              <th class="label">
                  <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>
              </th>
              <td class="data">
                 <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
         </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me an example of the new code?

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, but it still display empty dropdown attributes.

Comment: In the file attributes.phtml. But default value of empty dropdown attribute is "No"

Comment: @Jelle you're right, my mistake. Change `N/A` to `No` and you should be good to go

Comment: No that does not work. Because all attributes that do have the value No, and that do need that value, because it is correct, are also hide. I only need to hide empty dropdown attributes, not all attributes that do have value No.